# Validation of a number value if the number field is 0 by using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem with validating numbers. Whenever I input a zero on the number field, it's just still accepts the submission.

```
<tbody>

 <tr ng-repeat="item in requisitionItems | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter: searchText">
 <td>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="cbChecked()" ng-disabled="item.DeliveredQuantity != 0" ng-model="item.isItemSelected" />
 </td>
 @*<td ng-disabled="item.DeliveredQuantity != 0" ng-class="{red : item.DeliveredQuantity == 0}"><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="item.DeliveredQuantity != 0" ng-click="cbChecked()" ng-model="item.isItemSelected" /></td>*@
  <td ng-disabled="item.BalanceQuantity != 0" ng-class="{red : item.DeliveredQuantity == 0}"><span ng-bind="item.InventoryItemID"></span></td>
  <td ng-disabled="item.BalanceQuantity != 0" ng-class="{red : item.DeliveredQuantity == 0}"><span ng-bind="item.ItemName"></span></td>
  <td ng-disabled="item.BalanceQuantity != 0" ng-class="{red : item.DeliveredQuantity == 0}"><span ng-bind="item.Quantity"></span></td>
  <td ng-disabled="item.BalanceQuantity != 0" ng-class="{red : item.DeliveredQuantity == 0}"><span ng-bind="item.UnitOfMeasurement"></span></td>
  <td ng-show="deliveryType=='PartialDelivery'">
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.DeliveredQuantity"  class="form-control" min="1" max="100" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="Quantity">
  </td>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show an error

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('numbersOnly', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {


        if (parseInt(inputValue) <= 100 && parseInt(inputValue) > 0) {
          modelCtrl.$setValidity('numbersOnly', true);
          return inputValue;
        } else {
          modelCtrl.$setValidity('numbersOnly', false);
          return modelCtrl.$modelValue;
        }

      });
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.number = ''
}
```

Working example http://plnkr.co/edit/zhuPADr7Y7lUaQZgzIOk?p=preview